# Could a wizard learn every spell on the list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

So in the PHB it states by (a) finding a person willing to teach you the spell or finding it written and (b) spending the corresponding amount of gold and time a wizard can copy a new spell into their spellbook. (PHB p.114, "Your Spellbook")

**It is possible for a wizard to learn every spell a wizard can learn?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**It is possible for a wizard to get every spell on the Wizard list into their spellbook.**

It takes time, money, being of an appropriate level, and some scavenger-hunting. This, historically, is the defining feature of the wizard: the *breadth* of magic they (might) access. This, and "the never-ending quest to find more and rarer spells," as @GMJoe rightly reminds us =)

Of course, "spells prepared" is a different thing....

Comment: Is there one edition where spell books are limited to 100? You can always get more than one I would hope.

Comment: @FrancisJohn In certain editions the number of pages in a spellbook was limited, but there was never a restriction on the number of books you could own. (In fact, in every edition I know of that defined the capacity of spellbooks, "blank spellbook" was listed in the equipment list.)

Comment: Cantrips are in the wizard's spell list, but they are not written in the spellbook and hence can't be collected like other spells.

Comment: @Ruse that's... a good point. Will update when I've got a minute (or fifteen).

Answer (score -3):

Yes. With enough gold & time and the spells in one way or another (spellscrolls & other wizard's spellbooks).

Comment: This doesn't add anything that's not already covered by the other answer.

Comment: Hi Unexpected_Sage, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information.